# Conversion from string "9/18/2013" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

i am developing a web app in asp.net 4.0 . on data entry screen i have an check on contract expiry date , 
so i am using a if condition to check Is contract has expired or not.
this is my code

```
If dr_customer.Item("contract_T") < Me.txt_dateissue.Text Or dr_customer.Item("contract_F") > Me.txt_dateissue.Text Then
    Me.lab_error.Text = "Contract Expire"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

contract_F is contract start date and contract_T is contract end date (i am taking this data from database)
and dr_customer is data reader

when i execute application and insert data i received this error

Conversion from string "9/18/2013" to type 'Date' is not valid

Comment: You need to convert `Me.txt_dateissue.Text` to a date before doing your comparison. The compiler will not do it automatically.

Comment: Where is the code where you try the conversion?

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert `Me.txt_dateissue.Text` to `DateTime` in order to make the comparison

```
Dim dateIssue as DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Me.txt_dateissue.Text)
If  dr_customer.Item("contract_T") < dateIssue Or 
    dr_customer.Item("contract_F") > dateIssue Then
```

Comment: i use both functions Cdate() and datetime.parse() but no thing is working . i thing to perform comparison between two dates their format should be same. am i right?

Answer (score 3):

You need to parse the text from your `TextBox` into a `DateTime` object to be able to compare it to the `DateTime` objects that `contract_T` and `contract_F` represent:

```
Dim dateIssue As Date = DateTime.Parse(Me.txt_dateissue.Text)
If dr_customer.Item("contract_T") < dateIssue Or dr_customer.Item("contract_F") > dateIssue Then
    Me.lab_error.Text = "Contract Expire"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a difference between using Datetime.Parse instead of Cdate()?

Comment: `CDate` uses the current locale settings and the built-in date/time formats associated with it. In this case, it wouldn't make a difference, but if you needed to convert, for example, a long date/time string with 'Wednesday' in it, or a date/time string with a specific format, you'd need to use `DateTime.Parse`. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following uses `CDate()` before comparisons are made on date entries:

```
If dr_customer.Item("contract_T") < CDate( Me.txt_dateissue.Text) Or dr_customer.Item("contract_F") >  CDate(Me.txt_dateissue.Text) Then
    Me.lab_error.Text = "Contract Expire"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: i use both functions Cdate() and datetime.parse() but no thing is working . i thing to perform comparison between two dates their format should be same. am i right?